# Help making cotton candy - clumps and is wet?

Tags: candy

I have a mid-grade cotton candy machine (paragon classic 5) and I am having a lot of trouble getting it right. I am following the minimal instructions it comes with. Turn on the motor, full the hopper, turn on the heat to high, and turn down the heat when it starts to produce. I turn it down just to the point that it is still producing, but it's still flinging clumps quite regularly, which stick to the pan and are picked up with the next stick.

The resulting cotton candy also seems very heavy and wet. It looks fine at first, but after a few minutes it starts to look very wet and melty, even developing a blackish-brownish wetness.

I have less than a week to learn to use this right before I need it for an event. =(

Comment: What kind of sugar are you using and how are you storing it? From your description, it seems to have too much moisture in it